# how to write query for mongodb to pass in knp paginator in symfony2

Tags: mongodb, symfony-2.2

i am using knp paginator bundle for pagination.

i know to use knp paginator for doctrine. but i don't know in mongodb.

below code which show for doctrine ORM query which pass to knp paginator.

```
$em    = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
$dql   = "SELECT a FROM AdwindBannerBundle:Banner a";
$query = $em->createQuery($dql);
$pagination = $this->get('knp_paginator')->paginate($query,$page,10);
```

same way i want to use for ODM (mongoDB).

but i have confusion that what kind of query i have to use for ODM(mongodb) to pass in knp paginator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe

```
$dm    = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager();
$qb    = $dm->createQueryBuilder('AcmeDemoBundle:User');

$paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');
$pagination = $paginator->paginate(
    $qb,
    $this->get('request')->query->get('page', 1)/*page number*/,
    10/*limit per page*/
);
```